# Google Chome Extension development Autocomplete Code

Tags: chrome

I am using NetBeans for the Google Chrome Extension development and using 'ChromeExtensionPlugin' from http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49980/chromeextensionplugin . But this plugin is not supporting auto-complete code for the above development.

Is there any other plugin which support Google Chrome extension development autocomplete code with netbeans or any other IDE supporting autocomplete code? Any help will be highly appreciable.. Thanks in advance